# Помощь с библиотекой vk_api(бот вк)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Нужна помощь, дело в том, что бот отвечает в лс, но никак не хочет в беседе, пробовал многое, не получается. Рад буду любым доводам.
P.S Бот в беседы состоит, выданы все необходимые права доступа.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import calendar
import random
import string
import whois
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier, geocoder

token = "УКАЗАН"

di = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
give = di.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(di)



def __sendMeesage(id, text):
    di.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:

            message = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id

             # The function is a calendar. It does not work correctly, the code should be slightly tweaked.

            if message == '/calendar':
                __sendMeesage(id, calendar.month(2021, 8))

            # Generating a random password. If necessary, you can supplement the code.

            elif message == '/password':
                a = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
                b = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(8))
                __sendMeesage(id, f'You random password: {b}')

            # Function - domain name check. Displays brief information about the domain. The code should be added.

            elif message == '/domain':
                domain = 'google.com'
                domain_info = whois.whois(domain)
                for key, value in domain_info.items():
                    # print(key, ':', value)
                    __sendMeesage(id, f'{key} : {value}')

            #Function - brief information about the mobile phone number. Displays short info. by phone number.
            # Not completed yet.

            elif message == '/phone':
                a = phonenumbers.parse('+71234567890')
                __sendMeesage(id, f'Country - {geocoder.description_for_number(a, "ru")}')
                __sendMeesage(id, f'Mobile operator - {carrier.name_for_number(a, "ru")}')
                __sendMeesage(id, f'❗ The function was created in test mode and will be added in the future. ❗')
            else:
                __sendMeesage(id, '❗ I don`t speaking you! :( ❗ \n ⛔ My functionality: ⛔ \n ⛔ /calendar ⛔ \n '
                                  '⛔ /password ⛔ \n ⛔/domain ⛔ \n ⛔ /phone ⛔')
```

Comment: попробуйте условие с event.to_me на что-то ещё заменить

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло(

Comment: Сообщите в `VkLongPoll(di)` id вашей группы(`VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'ID вашей группы без кавычек')`) , иначе вы отправляете в ЛС

Comment: @Tehnorobot судя по всему бот страничный и с этим все верно. но вот то, что функция отправляет сообщение всегда в ЛС, вызывает вопросы. может, именно это автор под проблемой имеет в виду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, указывая только условие `event.to_me`, не создавая внутри разделы: `event.from_user` и `event.from_chat`, бот будет отвечать везде, только вот в чём Ваша ошибка:

```
if event.to_me:

    message = event.text.lower()
    id = event.user_id

    # Код ответов
```

Здесь Вы узнаете только `id пользователя`, и бот не сможет написать в беседу, не зная её `id`.
Добавьте после получения `id пользователя` - `chat_id = event.chat_id`

Теперь у Вас есть `id беседы`.
Идём дальше:

```
def __sendMeesage(id, text):
    di.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
```

Здесь указан метод только на **ответ в лс**. Добавим в аттрибуты переменную, при получении которой, будем отправлять в беседу.
Вот пример кода:

```
def __sendMeesage(id, text, chat=False):
    if chat == False: # Если False
        di.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
    elif chat == True: # Если True
        di.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
```

Готово, теперь при указании: `__sendMeesage(chat_id, text, True)` - текст отправится в беседу.

А при указании: `__sendMeesage(id, text)` - текст отправится в лс.

Едем дальше.
Возьмём для примера функцию календаря:

```
if message == '/calendar':
    __sendMeesage(id, calendar.month(2021, 8))
```

Здесь у Вас так и указывается: *отправить в лс*.
Давайте это исправим:

```
if message == '/calendar':
    if event.from_user: # Если нам написали в лс, то всё - то же самое
        __sendMeesage(id, calendar.month(2021, 8))
    elif event.from_chat: # Если нам написали в беседу
        __sendMeesage(chat_id, calendar.month(2021, 8), True) # Здесь указываем chat_id и в конце True, чтобы отправилось в беседу.
```

Готово! Надеюсь, я смог Вам помочь

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй написать if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat